# How can I run events in the aspx page and not server side?

Tags: asp.net, events, webforms

On the ASPX page alone, is there a way I can use a selectbox to run MVC code without being able to access the compiled server code?
The client does not have access to this code so I am trying to do the most basic things for them to avoid having to use the code.

I already tried javascript but javascript can't run codeblocks. 
So I am trying an asp server control with the event inside a script tag in the same aspx page.

```
<asp:dropdownlist runat="server" name="myselectbox" id="selectbox1" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Selection_Change">

void Selection_Change(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{ ...
```

but it doesn't seem to work. The page reloads but nothing runs in the event. 
Also I have a MASTER page and am stuck with MVC 2.

Comment: anything client side will have to be javascript, if you want it to work similarly in most browsers.  However, there were some software packages I've seen in the past (circa 2005) that could take your asp.net code and create a standalone client server.  This removed the need for IIS setup, etc., so you could showcase your portfolio at a client site, etc.

Comment: Humph OK. Well I will have to alert them of the bad news. I kept telling them I needed the source code. I saw some stuff where maybe i could get codeblocks to run in Javascript though. I can doublecheck.

Comment: That's usually code that gets inserted on the server side.  ASP.NET will inject the result of variables or code into the javascript, but the actual code emitted to the client will be regular javascript.  You can't natively run .net code in a browser without some sort of plugin.

Comment: Make sure you choose correct tags for your questions. Obviously you are using ASP.NET WebForms, not MVC.

Comment: I am actually using MVC. This is an MVC project but was trying out WebForms as a last effort. Using MVC HTML Helpers is even more reliant on the server code. Thanks again.